# Multilanguage Navigation

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, internationalization

I'm trying to get two translated nav menus, the default main nav and custom footer.

I've been able to get the main nav to appear in the correct language, but it doesn't drive to the translated node version it should be linking to it.

I've already been through every option I could find, with the `admin/config/regional/i18n/variable` path being the one that seems most correct, but no banana!

Any help would be appreciated! As this is all based on configuration options, I don't have any code to share.

Comment: By experience , you need to use several menus , one by langage available , its the easy way to customize menu and eventual make some difference between all. (if you need a link only on one langage by example, weight , etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as @Fky said, it's much easier to use one menu per language.

Then in menu block settings you can configure those menu blocks to appear only in one language. I'm also using menu block module which is adding extra functionality to menu generation:

https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block